# how to skip inputing acount name and password to enter admin pages in zencart 1.5.1

Tags: zen-cart

how to skip inputing acount name and password to enter admin pages in zencart 1.5.1
I installed zencart 1.5.1 in my PC which is only for practise and developing . 
The zencart will request me to enter admin acount name and password when time exceeded.
How to skip this login step?

Answer (score 0):

The Admin Keepalive Timer plugin will allow you to handle the "time exceeded" problem.
http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1526